# printing graph legend

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8

```
div.task_finished { background-color:#6b86a6; }
div.task_pending_execute { background-color:#93b8e2; }
div.task_cancelled  { background-color:#ff9966; }
div.task { background-color:#ffffcc; }
```

Now I want to print this

```
<div class="legend-container">
            <div class="legend">
                <div class="task_pending_execute"></div>
                <div class="legend-text">Executing</div>
            </div>
            <div class="legend">
                <div class="task_cancelled"></div>
                <div class="legend-text">Finished</div>
            </div>
        ...
</div>
```

[image: here what I've got]

For IE graph is rendered as image.

User browser set not to print `background-color` by default, but that's inacceptable in this concrete situation

I still don't want to subsitute 'color' div's here by images.

What css property should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a colored border, something like this:

```
div.task_finished { border-left:#6b86a6 solid 100px; height: 1em; }
```

However, I'm not sure if IE considers borders as background or foreground when printing.

[EDIT: another idea]

Another solution would be to use [Unicode Block Elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Block_elements) and then set the foreground (text) color.

```
<div>&#x2588;&#x2588;&#x2588;&#x2588;&#x2588;</div>
<div>█████</div>
```

However, this will fail on systems without proper unicode support, or without correct fonts.

Also, it will give you little control about what is the width of the legend, because different fonts have different widths. (maybe CSS `@font` can help you solve this, but I'm not sure)

Finally, maybe there are visible "seams" between each character, depending on the font. (this might be "fixed" by setting a negative `letter-spacing`)

Comment: IE prints borders, this seems to be a valid hack, but I already use border property :(

Comment: So... Maybe you want to enclose the DIV above with another DIV. So, the inner div has border behaving as the background, while the outer one has the border as an actual border.

Comment: Another solution is to use Unicode Block Elements. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: thanks for 'bold border + outer div' idea, that's just what I've looked for

Answer (score 1):

Not something you can really do anything about. Background colour/image printing is a printer option and not something you should really count on - http://css-tricks.com/dont-rely-on-background-colors-printing/